# Sort within subgroups that aren't next to each other - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample DF:

```
id sim   sub_group sub_group_rank
a. 0.90  4         1
a. 0.87  2         1
a. 0.80  3         2
a. 0.75  1         1
a. 0.73  3         3
a. 0.70  5         1
a. 0.68  3         1
b. 0.90  1         2
b. 0.87  2         2
b. 0.80  2         1
b. 0.75  3         1
b. 0.73  4         1
b. 0.70  5         1
b. 0.68  1         1
```

Here the logic:

1. Sort by `id` and `sim`
2. Sort within the sub group. NOTE: I need to maintain the order within each `id` and just reorder rows within a `sub_group` based one their `sub_group_rank`. Take a look at how `sub_group` 3 is reordered within `id` a.

Updated DF:

```
id sim   sub_group sub_group_rank
a. 0.90  4         1
a. 0.87  2         1
a. 0.68  3         1
a. 0.75  1         1
a. 0.80  3         2
a. 0.70  5         1
a. 0.73  3         3
b. 0.68  1         1
b. 0.80  2         1
b. 0.87  2         2
b. 0.75  3         1
b. 0.73  4         1
b. 0.70  5         1
b. 0.90  1         2
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach this in pandas.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the logic here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here but you can use sort_values() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: I added details on the logic. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.loc[(df.groupby(['id','sub_group'])
   .sub_group_rank.transform(lambda x: x.sort_values().index)
)]
```

Output:

```
    id   sim  sub_group  sub_group_rank
0   a.  0.90          4               1
1   a.  0.87          2               1
6   a.  0.68          3               1
3   a.  0.75          1               1
2   a.  0.80          3               2
5   a.  0.70          5               1
4   a.  0.73          3               3
13  b.  0.68          1               1
9   b.  0.80          2               1
8   b.  0.87          2               2
10  b.  0.75          3               1
11  b.  0.73          4               1
12  b.  0.70          5               1
7   b.  0.90          1               2
```